# Parameter sniffing with XML parameters

Tags: sql-server, t-sql

I'm currently trying to resolve a problem where a bad query plan is non-determinstically cached for one of my stored procedures.  A lot of resources indicate this sort of issue can be caused by parameter sniffing, but I'm not sure if my case applies.

Specifically, I have a single parameter that is of type XML, and the first thing I do in the sproc is to load it into a temp table.  Is this something that could be impacted by parameter sniffing?

(the reproduction is time costly, and like I said, non-deterministic, which is why I haven't just checked yet)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This was sort of a stupid problem: the table stats' sample size was far too small (pretty large table).  We upped the sample size significantly and everything is working smoothly again.

Answer (score 0):

I don't know what you mean by `plan is non-determinstically cached` for an execution plan can be either cashed or not cashed.
Parameter sniffling is used by server to figure out the most efficient execution plan according to the parameter value, which is used in some condition. Roughly speaking, with parameter sniffling sql-server decides if it is efficient to use some index. More about it you can read, for example [in this blog](http://blogs.technet.com/b/mdegre/archive/2012/03/19/what-is-parameter-sniffing.aspx).

So, answering your question, as you do not use the xml parameter in some condition but just load it into a temp table the execution plan can not be affected by parameter sniffling.

But, as long as you use a temp table, the execution plan will not be cashed in most cases and will be recompiled at every execution. If you want the plan to be cashed consider using table variables instead.

Hope this helps.

Comment: What I mean is that the conditions under which a _bad_ query plan is cached is non-deterministic (i.e., running the same shape and volume of queries only produces a bad query plan some % of the time).  I don't understand what you mean by the plan being recompiled every execution — it does get cached, and that's my problem (that it's generating different plans and caching the wrong one).

Comment: @RichardPianka Now I see your problem but it's hard to say what can be the cause without seeing code of the SP and the execution plans bad and good. Can you provide them? Also, if the SP is not executed often and 2 ms for recompilation doesn't matter, you can use RECOMPILE option http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms190439.aspx

Comment: Unfortunately, I can't actually show you the code.  I've also tried using WITH RECOMPILE, but in use cases with many subsequent calls  whose execution time is less than that of the recompile itself, there is a pretty sizable performance loss (3-4x).  So basically, I can't incur the extra cost of the recompile each time.